# stack: what means "No extra-dep setting found for package at URL"

Tags: haskell-stack

I have packages at github included in my stack.yaml. when i run stack solver I get the message: `No extra-dep setting found for package at URL:`

I cannot find documentation in the stack docs for this case. What does the warning indicate? what corrective steps are to be taken?

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- '.'
- location: /home/frank/Workspace8/repo8/uniform/uniform-algebras
  extra-dep: true
- location: /home/frank/Workspace8/repo8/uniform/uniform-time
  extra-dep: true
- location:  
      git: https://github.com/andrewufrank/uniform-strings.git
      commit:  ba8bd37567758c1807bf470b3dda4f471cee0f5f
      extra-dep: true
- location:  
      git: https://github.com/andrewufrank/uniform-error.git
      commit:  46c62fcf8b4d6b7a5a9a3622c724ab573fce295d
      extra-dep: true 
extra-deps:
- data-easy-0.7.0
- pipes-4.3.2
resolver: lts-8.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a warning message, safe to ignore it.  Not sure why this warning would appear, though, packages do seem to be marked with "extra-dep: true"

Answer (score 10):

You receive the error message because the last two package locations have the `extra-dep` field on a wrong level in the YAML hierarchy. Stack does not find them from where it expects them to be and behaves accordingly.

To fix the issue you should move the fields up in the hierarchy as follows:

```
- location:  
      git: https://github.com/andrewufrank/uniform-strings.git
      commit:  ba8bd37567758c1807bf470b3dda4f471cee0f5f
  extra-dep: true
- location:  
      git: https://github.com/andrewufrank/uniform-error.git
      commit:  46c62fcf8b4d6b7a5a9a3622c724ab573fce295d
  extra-dep: true
```

Ignoring the warning and not fixing the issue results in Stack regarding the dependencies as part of your project.  For example, when you ask Stack to run the tests in your project it attempts to run the tests in these dependencies too. Often this is unwanted and rather confusing.